# ANDROID Fragment not attached to Activity In a specific device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

Recently one of my users reported to me a very strange error happens when trying to deploy a Dialog fragment. This error has not occurred in any device except Gigabyte AV10 (Android version 4.4.2) I tried it with another device of the same version and runs smoothly.

The error occurs when the user leaves the dialog fragment. It is assumed that the AsyncTask has finished and when the user uses the resource returned by the server, the error occurs. The following code will explain better

This is the Dialog fragment

```
public class shareDialog extends DialogFragment implements ManagePool.InterfaceManagePool {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dialog, null);

    ctx = MainActivity.ctx;

    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    getVideoLink();

    return view;
}

private void getVideoLink() { //Get the video link from the server

    ManagePool newTask = new ManagePool(ctx);
    newTask.listener =this;
    newTask.execute("2",user_id,video_id);
}

public void onResume()
{super.onResume();

    youtube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //After this, error occurs

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://"+play_link)));

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void getVideoLink(String result) {

    if(result!=null)
    {
        play_link = result;
        link.setText(play_link);// The Stack trace says the error occurs here, But the UI displays it correctly
    }

}
```

And this is the AsyncTask that brings link from the server using REST:

```
public class ManagePool extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public interface InterfaceManagePool {

    void getVideoLink(String result);
}

public ManagePool(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

    dialog.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.loading));
    dialog.show(); 
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    dialog.dismiss();
    listener.getVideoLink(result);
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String Response = null;

     //REST STUFF
    Response = newConection.performCall(requestURL, postDataParams, "POST");
    //REST STUFF

    return Response;

}
```

STACK TRACE:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment shareDialog{41eb6558} not attached to Activity
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:620)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:642)
at dialog.shareDialog.getVideoLink(shareDialog.java:262)
at helpers.ManagePool.onPostExecute(ManagePool.java:74)
at helpers.ManagePool.onPostExecute(ManagePool.java:19)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do not understand what happens, because the video link is displayed correctly. I have asked the user to do nothing until the link will appear, but the error persists.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update your `getVideoLink()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void getVideoLink(String result) {
    if( result!=null && !isDetached() ) {
        play_link = result;
        link.setText(play_link);// The Stack trace says the error occurs here, But the UI displays it correctly
    }
}
```